# Printing results from cursor.fetchall() without the trailing 'L'

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, mysql-python, fetchall

I have a python code that accesses mysql through MySQLdb to run a select statement. I then use `cursor.fetchall()` to gather that output as an array, but the problem is it prints an `L` at the end of each output like so:

```
sql = "SELECT data1, data2  FROM table1, table2 ;"
cursor.execute(sql)
dataarray = cursor.fetchall()
print dataarray

>>> ((75379L, 45708L), ...)
```

But in my table, there are no L's, just the numbers. How can I ensure that it just fetches and prints the data without the L? I'd rather avoid using `[:-1]` on a string because then it changes my `None` values to `Non`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `L` indicates the [`long`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#long) integer type. In Python 2 that's used automatically for values that are too large to be represented as a plain integer.

[`MySQLdb`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) appears to just always return `long`s:

> While MySQL's INTEGER column translates perfectly into a Python
>   integer, UNSIGNED INTEGER could overflow, so these values are
>   converted to Python long integers instead.

Calling `str()` on those values should omit the trailing `'L'`.

Comment: So if I then update my table with these values, will it update correctly? As in the 75379L will be entered into a column with integer data type without an error?

Comment: Yes, `int` and `long` are interchangeable. BTW, if you print an individual value,  you won't see the trailing 'L'. You're seeing it because you're printing a container.

Comment: I find the docs confusing in that. Can you really overflow a python int but not a long with some value? I thought that distinction was gone many years ago?

Comment: @roganjosh: No, Python automatically creates a long integer if a value is too large to be represented as a plain integer. MySQLdb just seems to do that explicitly.